# jQuery mobile 1.3 left slide panel - phonegap and fixed header

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using jQuery mobile 1.3 for my app in phonegap. I would like to implement the left slide menu like facebooks's app. I have fixed header with data-position="fixed". When I open the app in chrome it works. When I open the App in phonegap it doesn't works, because the fixed header is not moving to the right.

Some solutions to fix this?

EDIT:

Here is very simple example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Page Title</title> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<style>
html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
html, .ui-mobile, .ui-mobile body {
    height: 435px;
}
.ui-mobile, .ui-mobile .ui-page {
    min-height: 435px;
}
.ui-content{
    padding:10px 15px 0px 15px;
}
.panel-content { padding:15px; }

#myhdr.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-position-left {
    border:1px solid red;
}
</style>
</head> 
<body>  
<div data-role="page" style="max-height:440px; min-height:440px;">
    <!-- defaultpanel  -->
    <div data-role="panel" id="defaultpanel" data-theme="b">    
        <div class="panel-content">
            <ul data-theme="d" data-icon="false" data-divider-theme="d" data-inset="false" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="keywords" data-role="listview" style="overflow:auto; height:200px;">
            <li><a data-rel="close"><img src="images/icon.png" class="ui-li-icon" />close</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /content wrapper for padding -->         
    </div><!-- /defaultpanel -->
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" id="myhdr">
        <h1>Panel Demo</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content"> 
        <a href="#defaultpanel" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="bars">Default panel</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am working with Cordova 2.2.0, but I have tested it now with Cordova 2.9.0 and it is the same situation. Somehow the browser in Phonegap doesn't apply some style to the fixed header.

Thanks
Nik

Comment: OK, the example code is there. It doesn't works :-(

Comment: Hey, man I checked your code its works fine with my device using phonegap
makesure the cordova path is correct.
And localize the files so that it takes less time to load the app.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is working for me, I am talking about Android hybrid app made in Phonegap.

Working jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/PMrDn/56/

```
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-position="left" data-display="push">
            <a data-role="button">Some button</a>
        </div>            

        <div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
            <a href="#mypanel">Open panel</a>
            <h1>Index page</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

        </div>
    </div>
```

What you require is **`data-display="push"`** attribute inside your panel. It will successfully push fixed header to the right. This works on Android 3+ and it will not work on Android 2.X, but this is not jQuery Mobile fault.

Comment: hey, but your header is not fixed. I mean when the header is fixed it not works

Comment: Hi this is not possible! I am trying it 1 day and this is not working for me. In the time where there is position:fixed, the header is not mobing anymore under phonegap. What to do?

Comment: Niko Nik i am facing the same issue if you found any solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to turn on hardware acceleration in the android manifest.xml file, or you need to turn transforms off.

I was able to do this with the following..

```
$(document).bind("pagebeforeshow", function(event, data) {
    // this doesn't seem to turn off animations
    //$(".ui-panel-menu").panel("option", "animate", false);
    // this does turn off animation
    $(".ui-panel-animate").removeClass('ui-panel-animate');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same issue in Android 4.1.2 and here's what I did to resolve the issue.

I added this code in my stylesheet

```
.ui-header.ui-panel-open {
    top:-1px; 
    position:absolute; 
    bottom: auto; 
}
```

and this script on my app.js

```
$( '.ui-panel' ).on( "panelbeforeopen", function( ) {

    $('.ui-header.ui-header-fixed').addClass('ui-panel-open');

} );

$( '.ui-panel' ).on( "panelclose", function( ) {

    $('.ui-header.ui-header-fixed').removeClass('ui-panel-open');

} );
```

and set data display of my panel to push ( data-display="push" )